# LWC picklist value undefined on initial load

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a `lightning-input-field` inside a `lightning-record-edit-form`, used to create records. The `field-name` is a picklist field which uses a Picklist Value Set, with one default value.

When the form is loaded, the initial field value is `undefined`, but displays the default value. When the picklist is used to select another value, it is changed from `undefined` to whatever was selected, as evidenced by the `onchange` handler output.

I can use `getObjectInfo` to `@wire` the object info and resolve the default record type Id (or hardcode the default `012000000000000AAA`), then use that value to `getPicklistValues` to `@wire` the default value for the picklist which seems to initialize the value.

That seems like a lot of work to get the field value to properly reflect the displayed value. Are there simpler ways to get this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is made as such by design. The variable (let's call it myValue) you are setting as the 'value' attribute of the lighting-record-edit-form is not initialized in Javascript I assume?

If you wish to use the form as a placeholder for one or more fields of a certain SObject (without ever submitting the form and e.g. using the onchange event as you are currently doing), I believe the only option to pre-populate the myValue variable would be as you describe in your original question (getObjectInfo + getPicklistValues).

However, when using a lightning-record-edit-form **with** a submit action, the currently filled in value (in this case the default value) will be set correctly in the *data.fields* properties of the *event* parameter of your onsubmit-handler.